# Spring Exception Handeling Production vs Development

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, exception

I am using Spring MVC and I am handling the Exception in the first way described here: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/spring-mvc-error-handling-flow.html

which is basically putting the following code in web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/uncaughtException</location>
</error-page>
```

Now, I need to make 2 types of views for production and development. For development, I will print the full stacktrace, for production, I would say something like: "Something bad happens, please try again later". I need suggestions to differentiate between production and development. I am using apache maven to compile and there is a flag "-Dbuild.type=dev" which says that it is a dev compilation.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at spring's `Environment` abstraction, described at http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/

Answer (score 0):

You can put a variable in your production and development maven profiles and map that to a java bean.

Here is the profile bit

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <system.serverType>PROD</system.serverType>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>qa</id>
        <properties>
            <system.serverType>QA</system.serverType>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then in /src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="system" class="com.company.project.System" 
    p:serverType="${system.serverType}"
/>
```

This then maps the build profile to your java class.

```
public class System {
    public static enum ServerType {PROD, QA, DEV} 

    private ServerType serverType;
    public void setServerType(ServerType serverType) {
        this.serverType = serverType;
    }
    public ServerType getServerType() {
        return serverType;
    }

    public boolean isProduction() {
        return serverType == ServerType.PROD;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I specify if it is production or development, when I compile?